# Gaminifaction plugin for Jira is required to get bug/task tracking process gamified

Tags: jira

The business we are running now requires the gamification of the process. I have installed and intagrated [Jira Hero](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/archive/com.madgnome.jira.plugins.jirachievements) and have found it outdated and should be [developed](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/16387953/jira-heros-future...). After some google/youtube research I found a few options only.

1. [Mambo.io](http://mambo.io) has has only paid version, being open source software 
   without community/free edition.
2. [SAP HANA Platform](https://hcp.sap.com/capabilities/collaboration/gamification.html) has paid version as well, however, we do not use SAP products at all.

How to gamify the bug/task tracking process in Jira?